# Android shared element transition on returning to Fragment with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, shared-element-transition

I have a `GridView` wrapped inside of a `ScrollView` inside the let's call Fragment A and some `CardViews` inside that `GridView`. I know `GridViews` are scrollable but I expanded the height of the `GridView` to it's content's height because I want the elements inside the `GridView` and the layout above that, both scroll together. I'm well aware of that this is not the correct way of using `GridView` but I have my own reasons to do this so ignore that.

Anyway the problem is that shared element (the `CardView`) transition works well on going from fragment A to fragment B but not when coming back from fragment B to fragment A with pressing back button or with `fragmentManager.popBackStack();`

I set the `transitionName` value of `CardViews` programmatically with unique values for each `CardView` in the adapter that I'v used it for `Gridview` and pass it to the Fragment B with bundle arguments on `CardView`'s `onClick` method. Then in the `onCreateView` method of Fragment B I set that same value to the `CardView` inside it too.

Here's the code I used it to switch to Fragment B:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentB()
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Defines enter transition only for shared element
            Transition changeBoundsTransition = TransitionInflater.from(mContext).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move);
            fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeBoundsTransition);
            bundle.putString("transitionName", "card" + p.getId());
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack("package_root")
                    .addSharedElement(cv, "card" + p.getId())
                    .commit();

        }
```

And here's the `onCreateView` method of FragmentB:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        String transitionName = getArguments().getString("transitionName");
        view.findViewById(R.id.cv_selected_package_card).setTransitionName(transitionName);
}
```

As I said above the shared element transition works well on going to the `FragmentB` but not when coming back from it.

What I think is happening is that the `FragmentA` gets reloaded on coming back from `FragmentB` and that's why the scroll state when leaving it and when coming back to it doesn't stay the same and it displays from top. But Scroll can't be the main problem here because even when I select the first `CardView` at the top without scrolling down, the share element transition doesn't work on navigating back.

The target API version is 25, build API version is 25 and I test the app on a virtual device android API level 25.

So any idea how can I solve this issue.

Comment: maybe you should consider overriding `onBackPressed`.

Comment: @MehranZamani and do what in it?
I tested going back with calling `fragmentManager.popBackStack();` but it didn't make a different.

Comment: i don't know what are you trying to do. maybe force redraw fragment by `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `replace()` method I was using to switch to the next fragment. This would destroy the fragment and remove it from fragment manager and add it back when needed again. So in order to prevent that from happening, I used the `add()` method to add the next fragment and `hide()` to hide the current one.

Here's the code:

```
Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_container_wrapper);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .hide(currentFragment)
                .add(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .addSharedElement(cv, "card" + p.getId())
                .commit();
```